# Multiplying a matrix with its transpose using cuBlas

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, cublas

I am trying to multiply a matrix with its transpose, but I couldn't manage to make correct sgemm call. Sgemm takes many parameters. Some of those like lda, ldb are confusing for me. If I call the function below with square matrix it works otherwise it is not working.

```
/*param inMatrix: contains the matrix data in major order like [1 2 3 1 2 3]
  param rowNum: Number of rows in a matrix eg if matrix is 
                 |1  1|
                 |2  2|
                 |3  3| than rowNum should be 3*/ 
void matrixtTransposeMult(std::vector<float>& inMatrix, int rowNum)
{
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasCreate(&handle);

    int colNum = (int)inMatrix.size() / rowNum;
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_InMatrix(inMatrix);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_outputMatrix(rowNum*rowNum);
    float alpha = 1.0f;
    float beta = 0.0f;

    cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_T, rowNum, rowNum, colNum, &alpha,
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_InMatrix.data()), colNum, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_InMatrix.data()), colNum, &beta,
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_outputMatrix.data()), rowNum);

    thrust::host_vector<float> result = d_outputMatrix;
    for (auto elem : result)
        std::cout << elem << ",";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    cublasDestroy(handle);
}
```

What am I missing? How to make correct sgemm call for matrix*matrixTranspose?

Answer (score 1):

Below settings worked for me, if I am missing something please warn me. I hope it will be useful for somebody

```
void matrixtTransposeMult(std::vector<float>& inMatrix, int rowNum)
{
    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasCreate(&handle);

    int colNum = (int)inMatrix.size() / rowNum;
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_InMatrix(inMatrix);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_outputMatrix(rowNum*rowNum);
    float alpha = 1.0f;
    float beta = 0.0f;

    cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_T, rowNum, rowNum, colNum, &alpha,
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_InMatrix.data()), rowNum, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_InMatrix.data()), rowNum, &beta,
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_outputMatrix.data()), rowNum);

    thrust::host_vector<float> result = d_outputMatrix;
    for (auto elem : result)
        std::cout << elem << ",";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    cublasDestroy(handle);
}
```